# Python Setup gets IndexError?

Tags: python-3.x, setup.py, index-error

I am trying to create a .exe file from my Python file. My setup file contains the following code (which was generated using the PyBuilder application):

```
# setup.py
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

import sys

sys.stdout = open('screen.txt','w')
sys.stderr = open('errors.txt','w')

setup(name='Crypto Calculator',
      version='1.0',
      author='RedCode',
      data_files=[],
      windows=[{'script':'Crypto Calculator.py',
                'icon_resources':[(1,'')],
                }])

print("---Done---")
```

When I run the command `pyinstaller setup.pyw` I get the `IndexError: tuple out of range` error. When I try running the pyinstaller command on my actual application's file, it still gives me the same error.

How can I correct this problem and successfully create a Python exe file.

Comment: you are using it wrong. if you have installed pyinstaller just simply type the command pyinstaller file.py, no need of creating this setup file

Comment: @babygame0ver I just tried that and it still gives the same error. I have added this information to my question now.

Comment: can you show us the screenshot in the question

Comment: A screenshot of the error?